# how to write the code snippet into kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I have a question and don't know how to write in kotlin: if the list is null, I need to return a empty list. if the list has some elements, I need to convert the elements and let the list contains the new type of element.

is the code like :

list?:listof()

but where to put the convert code

Comment: `list.orEmpty().map { ... }` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With non-nullable lists, the general way to convert elements from a list is to create a new list with the converted elements using `.map { ... }`:

```kotlin
val listWithConvertedElements = list.map { convert(it) }
```

(where `convert()` is just an example to represent your own conversion code).

When your list is nullable, you cannot call `.map()` on it directly, but you can use the safe dereference operator `?.`. This will only call `map` if the list is not null, otherwise it will just return null directly:

```kotlin
val listWithConvertedElementsOrNull = list?.map { convert(it) }
```

Combining this with your (correct) use of the elvis operator `?:`, you get the following:

```kotlin
val listWithConvertedElementsOrEmpty = list?.map { convert(it) } ?: emptyList()
```

(`emptyList()` is the same as `listOf()` without arguments, but it expresses the intent better)

Comment: `.orEmpty()` is another option. Given that this function even exists, I assume it is preferred to `?: emptyList()`. It’s nice in function chains because it reduces use of parentheses. You can use it up front to avoid question marks.

Comment: Right. I just tend to avoid extensions on nullable types for some reason. It doesn't "feel right" to me. Maybe it has to do with the fact that a change in nullability can go unnoticed and leave a useless `.orEmpty()` lying around. Not sure if there are inspections for this that would play the same role as the compiler warning for using elvis or safe-dereference operators on non-nullable types

Comment: There's an inspection for `.orEmpty()` so it would warn you the same way it would for a useless `?:`.